# WiX / MSI refering to a file from a custom action in C++

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Is there a way to refer to a file declared on wix code, for instance:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="MAIN_INSTALLLOCATION">
      <Component Id="CMP_config_system" Guid="a430710e-a95b-48d7-acbe-3bf4e6b2c8fc">
        <File Id="FILE_config_system" KeyPath="yes" Source="config_system.ini"/>
      </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

In a custom action coded in C++, for instance (see question marks)

```
UINT __stdcall entryPoint(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
   //...
   LPWSTR filePath = NULL;
   hr = WcaGetProperty(???, &filePath);
   //...
}
```

So this way one could open and edit that file base on different things?

**EDIT same method as exposed by @NC1 but with WiX API**

```
// ...
const std::wstring APPDATA_DIR     = L"AppDataDir";
const std::wstring CONFIG_SYSTEM   = L"config_system.ini";

LPWSTR path = NULL;
hr = WcaGetProperty(APPDATA_DIR.c_str(), &path);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get Path");

config_system_path = std::wstring(path) + CONFIG_SYSTEM;
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do it. My custom action is scheduled after install files so I get the directory in which it was installed to and append the file I would like to edit(for me text files), not sure if this is the only way but it works for me.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
char szLocation[MAX_PATH];
LPWSTR szInstallLocation = NULL;
CString lpszString;

hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "NAMEOFCUSTOMACTION");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"MAIN_INSTALLLOCATION",&szInstallLocation);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get install location");

wcstombs(szLocation, szInstallLocation, 260);
strcat(szLocation, "\config_system.ini");
```

Where `szLocation` will then have the full path. Hope this helps

Comment: Reading the property vs the target path of the same directory is probably a wash, but know that MsiGetTargetPath exists. However: note that the dirproperty will have a trailing backslash on it so your strcat doesn't need to have one itself. (Warning: use of wcstombs will lose characters from the path that are not on the ACP, and use of strcat may be asking for a buffer overflow.)

Comment: Thanks @NC1, that's pretty same what I'm doing right now but I thought it might be another way to refer directly to some particular File. Nevertheless, I edited my question so you can have this method but with WiX API on C++.